# ID which is available in table1 but not available in table2, check it date wise

Tags: sql, sql-server

Question: ID  which is available in table1 but not available in table2, check it date wise. Need query in SQL.

Example: Table1:

| date | id |
| --- | --- |
| 1-1-2020 | 1234 |
| 1-1-2020 | 5678 |
| 1-1-2020 | 6789 |
| 2-1-2020 | 567 |

Table2:

| date | id |
| --- | --- |
| 1-1-2020 | 'b43v1234 |
| 1-1-2020 | 5678vgb' |
| 2-1-2020 | 'b43v1234 |

Result need:

| date | id |
| --- | --- |
| 1-1-2020 | 6789 |
| 2-1-2020 | 567 |

I tried

```sql
    Select table1.id, table1.date
    from table1
    left join table2 on table1.date = table2.date
        and table2.id like concat('%',table1.id,'%')
    where table2.id is null;
```

But not getting correct results. It's not considering this type of match
b43v1234 means if 1234 in table 1 and in table2 b43v1234 is available in same date means it's match so I don't want to return 1234 but 1234 is also coming in result.

Comment: Please provide table structures and what you have done so far that has not worked?

Comment: This question as it stands does now show the SQL you tried, the table schema/structure and will be closed unless you modify it.  Jon has a nice writeup and checklist to help you https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/  (and related information is on this site)

Comment: Select table1.id,table1.date from table1 left join table2 on table1.date=table2.date and table2.id like concat('%',table1.id,'%') where table2.id is null;

Comment: [edit] any additional information directly into your question. And please read [How to add tables to a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302471/how-to-put-tables-in-stack-overflow)

Comment: By this query it's not getting consider b43v1234

Comment: Yaah, edited in question. Thanks

Comment: Please note the code formatting option in the editor, and I highly recommend formatting your data so its easy to read. As it stands I haven't got time to try and make sense of the data but if it was tabular I would be able to see it at a glance.

Comment: Read up on INNER JOIN vs OUTER JOIN

Comment: Can you formulate your SQL in plain english, what would be the steps to make a match between the tables? And are you fundamentally asking for a `NOT EXISTS` (even though you wrote it as a left join)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Charlieface indicates it appears you want a `not exists`. The following returns your desired results.

```
declare @Table1 table ([date] date, id int);

insert into @Table1 ([date], id)
values
('2020-01-01',1234),
('2020-01-01',5678),
('2020-01-01',6789),
('2020-01-02',567);

declare @Table2 table ([date] date, id varchar(8));

insert into @Table2 ([date], id)
values
('2020-01-01','b43v1234'),
('2020-01-01','5678vgb'),
('2020-01-02','b43v1234');

select t1.id, t1.[date]
from @Table1 t1
where not exists (
    select 1
    from @Table2 t2
    where t1.[date] = t2.[date]
    and t2.id like concat('%',t1.id,'%')
);
```

| id | date |
| --- | --- |
| 6789 | 2020-01-01 |
| 567 | 2020-01-02 |

Note: I recommend in future setting up all your questions in this way, with DDL+DML to create the sample data, your attempt, and tabular results.

Also best to use an unambigious date format as you never know what country (and therefore date format) people answers might be in.

Comment: Did this answer your question?

Comment: Thanks Dale.. Thank you very much